# Networking for Guest Domains with Xen

Tags: networking, ip, xen

I experience some difficulties with the Xen Hypervisor 4.1. We have a server with the IP address 192.168.75.xyz with running Xen on it. When deploying a guest domain it obtains the IP address 192.168.122.xy. Since we do not cover IP addresses in the range of 192.168.122.xy I can not access or ping the guest domain.

What I would like to do is to obtain a valid IP address via DHCP for the guest domain. It seems to me that the Xen Hypervisor itself is generating an IP address for the guest domain instead of receiving it from the DHCP server and setting it for the guest domain. Am I right? Can I change this behavior?

I already tried to set a static IP address in the guest domain itself, but didn't work out for me. I could not ping or access the guest domain.

My settings for the /etc/network/interfaces on domain 0 are as follows:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The Xen network interface
auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports p1p2

# The primary network interface
auto p1p2
iface p1p2 inet manual
```

If you need more information, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Xen does its own DHCP and assigns IP addresses for its guests in its subnetwork. To overcome this default behavior of Xen you just have to enter

```
vif = [ 'bridge=xenbr0' ]
```

in your guest configuration file and Xen will assign IP addresses of the subnet the domain0 itself belongs to. I hope that anyone having the same issue can fix this easily.

This solution worked for me:
http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Xen_domainU_Guest_has_an_IP_address_on_192.168.122_subnet_instead_of_the_subnet_to_which_the_domain0_host_belongs